# why its not possible to change a global variable within a block?

Tags: variables, global, block

i am new in javascript and need some help

i defined a global variable and change it in a block, but the variable is not changed after the block what is wrong here?

in console i get

09:48:40.085    info    javascript.0 (22123) script.js.Mein_Haus.test2: main bevor function call 555
09:48:40.085    info    javascript.0 (22123) script.js.Mein_Haus.test2: in function out of block after change 555
09:48:40.085    info    javascript.0 (22123) script.js.Mein_Haus.test2: main after function call 555
09:48:40.086    info    javascript.0 (22123) script.js.Mein_Haus.test2: in block bevor change 555
09:48:40.086    info    javascript.0 (22123) script.js.Mein_Haus.test2: in block after change111

```
var fs = require('fs');
var toWriteListXml = '/home/uwe/bin/out.txt'
var content;
var global = {}
global.storedData = 555



console.log('main bevor function call ' + global.storedData)
LoadData()
console.log('main after function call ' + global.storedData)



function LoadData() {
fs.readFile(toWriteListXml, function read(err, data) {
if (err) {
    throw err;
}
content = data
console.log('in block bevor change ' + global.storedData)
global.storedData = 111
console.log('in block after change' + global.storedData)
});
console.log('in function out of block after change ' + global.storedData)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `read` is an asynchronous callback. It doesn't execute right away, rather it executes when the file loading has completed.
When you call `console.log('main after function call '`, the callback has not yet been executed (as you can see by the order of the logs you get), and the variable has not yet been set.